# NodeJS App npm install error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm following this tutorial to install NODE + EXPRESS and MongoDB http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

I did all the stuff asked and after CMD npm install I recive the following error:

[image]

The content of bulderror.log is here http://pastebin.com/8j9YCYZG

Comment: Please post text instead of images when the information is textual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Node-gyp require the installation of additional dependencies.**

Please note the installation instructions on the pages [TooTallNate/node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) and [Error compiling bcrypt - node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573488/error-compiling-bcrypt-node-js).