# When installing Drywall I have an issue with Bcrypt

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-8.1, bcrypt, drywall

I'm try to install Drywall : [Drywall js](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall)
And I have a problem with Bcrypt, even when I follow all the instructions below, since I install :

- Install latest 2.x Python, download Python (I downloaded 2.7.9)
- Install Visual Studio 2012/13 Express (or other)
- Install Windows SDK (for Windows 7 / 8)
- Install Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1g, download it from here (I loaded "Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2a" latest)

I'm using Windows 8 X64, nodejs >0.12.7, bcrypt : 0.8

How can I solve this issue please? The error is below:

```
if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node
     rebuild )
    Génération des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la génération en parallèle, ajoutez le commutateur "/m".
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(362,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be se
    t to an invalid version number. [C:\SourceCode\MEAN\eventbook\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
      blowfish.cc
      bcrypt.cc
      bcrypt_node.cc
    c:\users\naoufal\.node-gyp\0.12.7\deps\uv\include\uv-win.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory (..\src\bcrypt_node.cc) [C:\SourceCode\MEAN\eventbook\node_modules\
    bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
    ..\src\bcrypt.cc(232): warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data [C:\SourceCode\MEAN\eventbook\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\SourceCode\MEAN\eventbook\node_modules\bcrypt
    gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
    npm ERR! node v0.12.7
    npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    
    npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.4 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\SourceCode\MEAN\eventbook\npm-debug.log
```

Thanks in advance!!!

PS: I've already seen this answer but deosn't work for me : [error compiling bcrypt node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573488/error-compiling-bcrypt-node-js)[Error compiling bcrypt - node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573488/error-compiling-bcrypt-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NodeJS its better to use a javascript version of bcrypt which is  [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs)

In order to switch to bcryptjs do

```
npm i -S bcryptjs
```

then require it instead of bcrypt in **schema/user.js** (twice)

replace

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
```

with

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
```

and it shold work.
There's also a documentation on drywall 
https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/wiki
i think it also mentioned there somewhere.