# Cannot find module 'bcrypt'

Tags: node.js

I am getting error Cannot find module 'bcrypt' in nodejs application

I have tried to install it using ***npm install bcrypt***  but still getting the issue.

```
node app.js
```

**Error message:**

```
Dec 30 2015 5:22:18 PM+05:30 - info: Connected to database:  
postgres://testdb:see2@$W@localhost/testdb

Dec 30 2015 5:22:18 PM+05:30 - error: Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\...\server\modules\user\model
s\user.js:11:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Using `npm install bcrypt` command can't resolve the issue for me.

I tried the commands below and my issue resolved.

```
npm install node-gyp -g
npm install bcrypt -g

npm install bcrypt --save
```

Comment: `node-gyp` was giving me issues. Followed the steps above and voila! Thanks buddy.

Comment: If you get access error when installing bcrypt, try this : sudo npm install --unsafe-perm --verbose -g bcrypt

Comment: It should be npm install bcrypt --save. Works for me!

Answer (score 91):

The solution for me was to `npm rebuild`.

Answer (score 28):

use **bcryptjs** instead bcrypt
this is worked for me

```
npm install bcryptjs --save
```

Comment: i still get same error with that: 

**SyntaxError: Named export 'compare' not found. The requested module 'bcryptjs' is a CommonJS module,**

Comment: If you're using TS you also need to install @types/bcryptjs as dev dependency, remember remove @types/bcrypt

Answer (score 24):

**The Solution is pretty basic,** I've solved this Error / Bug with the following steps:

**Step 1:** Uninstall the bcrypt package with this command :

npm uninstall bcrypt

**Step 2:** Then ReInstall it :

npm install bcrypt

Comment: Wow! It saves me a lot of time! It actually works! Thanks! :)

Comment: This simple approach worked perfectly! . Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

It should be `npm install bcrypt --save`. Works for me!

And, if you have others issues after install it, you can check your packages with **[npm-check](https://github.com/dylang/npm-check)**.

Answer (score 10):

Solution 1: lengthy method is : Install all dependencies first.

**npm install -g windows-build-tools,
npm install -g node-gyp**

then, install bcrypt : **npm install bcrypt**

Solution 2: easy method. No dependencies installation required.

**npm install bcryptjs**

...You might have installed bcrypt but it seems like the installation was not successful for some reason. check the package.json file. If you cannot find bcrypt, the installtion was unsuccessful. You have to install again.

As everyone explained, it because of lack dependencies that your installation was unsuccessful. You can checkout the required dependencies in the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Note:
To use bcrypt: 
  **var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');**
.....

to use bcryptjs.
**var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');**

for reference: 
**https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs**

Comment: what's the second way?

Comment: does it (the first solution) work on windows only?  cause I see you installed `windows-build-tools`

Answer (score 8):

Before using `npm install`, change the `package.json` file dependencies, i.e.

```
"bcrypt":"0.7.6"
```

to

```
"bcrypt":"*"
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

1) Delete any `bcrypt` folder in `nodemodules` folder, folder may have been created due to your repeated tries.
(`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`)

2) run this code `npm install --save bcryptjs`
e.g -

```
C:\Projects\loginapp>npm install --save bcryptjs
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. You need to delete old files!!!

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me as I was installing a package from github that had an older version of bcrypt as a dependency.

Just uninstall bcrypt to clear out the old version and install a new version:

```
npm uninstall bcrypt
npm install bcrypt
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, `npm rebuild` alone didn't solved it. I also had to:

```
$ npm install -g node-gyp
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ npm rebuild
```

`npm rebuild` was trying to run `make`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that bcrypt was depreciated at version 1.0.3 as it was susceptible to a wrap-around bug. NPM recommends installing version 2.0.0.

So, if you wish to save it, just run the command:

```
npm install bcrypt@2.0.0 --save
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `bcrypt` with typescript

```
npm i --save @types/bcryptjs
```

Helped me solve the error above.

Answer (score 2):

If none of these examples didn't work, you should try to downgrade Node version installed:

E.g from Node version 10 to version 9

```
npm install node@<version of node>
```

Comment: I had trouble with node 12. I downgraded to node 10 and removed the `node_modules` folder. After reinstalling, it worked!

Comment: @joeytwiddle If even that won't work, the best solution is to install `bcryptjs`. It has zero dependencies and it's not influenced by OS used.But first it needs to be uninstalled `bcrypt`.

Comment: I was trying to run this
https://github.com/komarserjio/notejam
The express version over node 12.  I've tried this solution downgrading to node v10 and it worked! thanks.

Comment: One more tip would be to use bcryptjs instead of bcrypt. Bcrypt has a problem with dependencies very often

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the g++ compiler version in your linux system.
To update the compiler just run the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9


npm install bcrypt --save
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm running **Ubuntu 16.04** on **DigitalOcean** *(512 MB / 1 CPU, 20
>   GB SSD)*

The following worked for me:

1. Scale your droplet up to the 1 GB RAM option ($10/mo)
2. Run each of the following commands (one at a time)

   ```
   sudo npm install node-gyp -g
   sudo apt-get install python
   sudo apt-get install make
   sudo apt-get install g++
   ```
3. Then try again with:

   ```
   npm install bcrypt --save
   ```
4. Scale droplet back down to the 512 MB option

Answer (score 1):

I followed some course, and for me it didn't work.
My mistake was:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt.js');
```

But when I changed it to

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
```

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

- Node Version vs   Bcrypt Version
- 0.4               <= 0.4
- 0.6, 0.8, 0.10    >= 0.5
- 0.11              >= 0.8
- 4                 <= 2.1.0
- 8                 >= 1.0.3
- 10, 11            >= 3
- 12                >= 3.0.6

I had the same issue, after I installed the bcrypt particular version depends on your node version, it started to working.

In my case my nodeJS version was 12.3.0 , so I installed by specifying the version
" npm install bcrypt@3.0.6."

I hope it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

if your issue didn't resolved. The below syntax will surely provide you a solution.
To use bcrypt: var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
To use bcryptjs. var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

Answer (score 0):

I can't run any npm commads. so, I download from this link `https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js`
create folder bcrype and use it.
Solve now.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue resolved by below steps:
Nothing above solved my issue,
1) rm -rf node_modules in your project directory
2) rm package-lock.json
3) just check you have your package.json file now
4) npm install

Thats it, you will get bcrypt installed properly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
npm install bcryptjs
```

Then:

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete bcrypt module from your node modules.
Then try the below steps:

1) `npm install node-gyp -g`

2) `npm install bcrypt -g`

3) `npm install bcrypt -save`

This will definitely resolve the issue.

Comment: "--save" not "-save". Also you can do `npm install bcrypt -g --save`

Comment: this is not working for me 
node v8.16.1
npm 6.4.1  
npm install node-gyp -g
npm install bcrypt -g
npm install bcrypt --save

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are in a **stable version of node** too. If you are working with `n`, you only need to:

```
sudo n stable
```

And then again:

```
npm install bcrypt --save
```

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an error you are facing when using something like Travis CI, consider using `npm install --build-from-source`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be because there is no this essential

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python
```

Then agregate `bcrypt` with 
if you're using **npm**:

```
npm install bcrypt
npm rebuild
```

or if you're using **yarn**:

```
yarn add bcrypt
yarn install
yarn build
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `bcrypt@3.0.6` and `@types/bcrypt@3.0.0` with `node 13.7.0` environment. I was running into error `cannot find binding  .../node_modules/../bindings/bcrypt_lib.node`

I ran this to resolve issue:

- `npm i -g node-gyp`
- `npm i bcrypt --save`

This upgraded to `bcrypt@3.0.8`

Answer (score 0):

Using `npm install bcrypt` command can't resolve the issue for me.

finally, i fixed commands below and my issue resolved.

```
npm install node-gyp -g
# bcrypt reqired node-pre-gyp
npm install -g node-pre-gyp
npm install bcrypt -g

npm install bcrypt --save
```

node -v
v8.16.1

npm -v
6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

If the problem could not solved after applying the workarounds above, you may try to update version in `package.json` as mentioned on **[[Fix bug] update bcrypt to 3.0.7](https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vidly-api-node/pull/25/commits/4ba3ea6311f0ffe9224e62973e75b831966c4a3c)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to install bcryptjs. Use npm install bcryptjs --save It worked for me when I was stuck here.

Comment: bcryptjs is more simple to use than bcrypt because it is written purely in javascript, but beware it will be slower than the c++ version

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version and then go to this link https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js to match compatible bcrypt version with your node.js version

I am using node.js v14.7.0 and when I tried to run 'npm install bcrypt or bcryptjs'
it gives me errors
then I run npm install bcrypt@5.0.0

and the error fixed.

Version Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

First check node-modules folder for a folder with this name `bcrypt`. If it exists with another name just rename it; for example `bcrypt-pbkdf` must be edited to `bcrypt`. If there isn't such a folder, do this in cmd:

```
npm install node-gyp -g
# bcrypt reqired node-pre-gyp
npm install -g node-pre-gyp
npm install bcrypt -g
npm install bcrypt --save
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because `bcryptjs` has a different name.

To fix it simply,

- `cd node_modules` Go to node_modules folder on your application
- `ln -s bcryptjs bcrypt` OR for Windows `mklink /D bcryptjs bcrypt`

This creates a link of `bcryptjs` directory to `bcrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after running the install commands and the commands suggested by others, my `package.json` file was not being updated. I manually included this dependency in my `package.json` file like below:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "bcrypt": "5.0.1"
    ...
}
```

And then `saved` the file and ran `npm install --save -g`, this installed the missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

- Deleted node_modules
- Delete package-lock.json
- Reinstalled all the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If above solutions don't work just delete `Node modules` and `package.json` then `npm install --save` and then `npm install bcrypt --save`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using yarn, try installing with npm then just deleting the lock file after.

It seems it's an issue specific to `yarn`

See https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/1023

```bash
npm install bcrypt
yarn
rm package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 0):

When `npm i bcrypt -g` didn't work for me,
then I run `npm i bcrypt -d` and that did work.