# Error "bcrypt is not defined" after clicking submit button in registration page

Tags: node.js

I have designed the registration page in node.js but after clicking the submit button in the registration form I am getting the below error :

Some error occurred: Reference error : "bcrypt is not defined"

My user model is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({

    userName            : {type:String,default:'',required:true},
    firstName           : {type:String,default:''},
    lastName            : {type:String,default:''},
    email               : {type:String,default:''},
    mobileNumber        : {type:Number,default:''},
    password            : {type:String,default:''},
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var myuser = this;
  var SALT_FACTOR = 5;

  if (!myuser.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(myuser.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      myuser.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('myUser',userSchema);
```

Comment: Yes, it seems you didn’t define it anywhere. How would Node guess what you mean?

Comment: Would you please have a look at my answer on **[Cannot find module 'bcrypt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546272/cannot-find-module-bcrypt/61558938#61558938)**?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install and then require a bcrypt library, it isn't built into Node, thus why it is `undefined`.

There are several available, [bcrypt.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js) is one that is written in native JS and still maintained. There is also the [bcrypt package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) that binds to the C++ bcrypt implementation, which would run faster than pure JS implementations, but you might run into [compilation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573488/error-compiling-bcrypt-node-js); so you might want to stick to a JS implementation if you don't know how to troubleshoot that sort of thing.

To install bcrypt.js you would use npm: `npm install bcryptjs`

Then, require it at the top of your code along with mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
yes I have installed bcryptjs and included it within my mongoose. But when I click on Signup button, it is generating a random password, not the password which I am entering while filling up the signup form.

Answer (score 0):

yes I have installed bcryptjs and included it within my mongoose.
But when I click on Signup button, it is generating a random password, not the password which I am entering while filling up the signup form.

Answer (score 0):

First install bcrypt using the following command in the npm

```
`npm install --save bcrypt`
```

Later import the bcrypt module in the backend node js service using:

`const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');`

Then using the bcrypt.hash() method we can encrypt the message or password.