# Heroku Application Error, after app is successfully deployed

Tags: express, heroku, mern, heroku-cli

[Link to Live site](https://mern-crud-goal.herokuapp.com/)

This is a `MERN App`. It works fine in `Development mode` but, for some reason, after `successful` deployment on heroku, I am getting the `Application Error`.

Also, when I try to access the https://git.heroku.com/mern-crud-goal.git
heroku git, it shows `method not allowed error`.

All my code is in this repo [github repo](https://github.com/ntanwir10/mern-goal-setter)

I am fairly new to mern stack and absolutely new to heroku. Not exactly sure where I going wrong.

`goalRoutes.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const {
  getGoals,
  setGoals,
  updateGoals,
  deleteGoals,
} = require("../controllers/goalController");

const { protect } = "../middleware/authMiddleware.js";

router.route("/").get(protect, getGoals).post(protect, setGoals);

router.route("/:id").put(protect, updateGoals).delete(protect, deleteGoals);

module.exports = router;
```

[[image: Error on heroku after deployment]

[image: This the error that I see, after heroku logs --tail on cmd from my project dir]

Comment: Could you paste the code of `goalRoute.js`?

Comment: Please try to create a new file called `Procfile` in the root directory of the project, e.g. https://github.com/pprathameshmore/QuoteGarden/blob/master/Procfile

Comment: Tried that. Same Application error issue. Now, in heroku logs `Error: Cannot find module 'bcryptjs'` But, it's already installed in package.json and I had installed it using `npm i bcrypt --save` command.

Comment: Could try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546272/cannot-find-module-bcrypt?

Comment: Yes, I did tried them all. Still no luck