# Why does bcrypt need C++ and Python?

Tags: python, c++, node.js, npm, bcrypt

I've noticed that the node.js Javascript package for bcrypt requires lots of non-Javascript libraries - C++, Python 2.7, etc.

Why is this necessary?  Is there something special about encryption that requires non-Javascript languages?

Comment: Looks like the node.js package is nothing more than a thin wrapper over the python bcrypt library (which itself uses a CPython module, I would guess for performance reasons). As you can see in the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573488/error-compiling-bcrypt-node-js?rq=1 there is also a pure JS package available, which I guess will be some orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Primarily because of code reusability - why would people bother writing all crypto/hash libraries for all languages, not to mention the time it takes to test those, just so you can have it 'native' everywhere? If one writes a library in C/C++, you can compile and use it on pretty much any platform in pretty much any language, so that's why those 'popular' libraries tend to be written mostly in C/C++ and you just get a wrapper for your desired language to make it easier to interface. In case of bcrypt, it's essentially a Python-wrapped C module, hence the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

A algorithm like bcrypt never depends on a specific language. All general-purpose-langauges like C, Java, Pyton, JS, PHP etc.etc. can be sued to implement such algorithms.

Why they chose to use eg. C instead of just JS is likely because, at least with the currently available tools (compiler, interpreter etc.), C programs are much faster than JS. Encrypting large data sets shouldn't be unnecessary slow.